# How do I set up Netbeans to develop for Android in OS X?

Tags: java, android, macos, netbeans

I'm fairly new to the world of coding, but I took a Java class last fall and I really excelled in it, and I'm anxious to keep the ball rollin.  We talked a little bit about Android development in class, and I'm certain that if I could just get Netbeans set up properly, I could really do a lot with it.  I managed to get Xcode set up to use SDL using the Lazy Foo guides, but I haven't had any luck finding a similar guide for setting up Netbeans for Android development in OS X.

The closest I could find was this:
[Setting up your Development Environment](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-(Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans))

But the directions seemed kind of vague to me, and I ended up getting stuck when I ran the libGDX setup JAR file, and I got this message: "You have no build tools!  Update your Android SDK with build tools version: 20.0.0" but I already did download the Android SDK, so I don't know what's wrong!

I have lots of books on Android development, but nothing on actually setting up my chosen IDE!  There must be a step by step tutorial on this out there somewhere, right?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you insist on NetBeans? Android Studio is by far better env and official way to develop android apps.

Answer (score -1):

Here do the following
1)download the latest version of jdk install it and set up your environmental variables.
2)download android studio and use it.
3)happy coding

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes, I've done all that, and I do have android studio, but I like NetBeans, and my professor recommended it for developing android apps. So no one has any idea why libGDX might be giving me that error?

Comment: So to do it your way you have to download ADT plugin from google and also install the android SDK

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html here's the link to get you started

Comment: Thanks, but I've already done all that.  I guess I'll just use Android Studio.